# Equivalent of SPRelativeDateTime.GetRelativeDateString in CSOM sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

What is the equvalent API for **`SPRelativeDateTime.GetRelativeDateString`** in sharepoint 2013 Client object model

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://your.site"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {

        DateTime DateInPast = new DateTime(2014, 4, 14, 18, 38, 0); 
        string DateString; 
        //the difference between DateTime.Now and file past are about 4 minutes
        DateString = SPRelativeDateTime.GetRelativeDateString(web, DateTime.Now, DateInPast); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately after doing all the googling I was unable to find.

To complete the task I am using **jquery.timeago**. It's a tiny and wonderful plugin that resolved my problem. You can download it from [timeago website](http://timeago.yarp.com/)